# Getting out of a recursive loop in Python

Tags: python, django

I have the following code, which results in Python "quitting unexpectedly":

```
def profile_videos_sort_and_filter(profile, sort, filter, uncredited_videos, list_of_credits=[]):
    """Given a sort and filter, this will order the credits and return a credit_set."""
    if filter == 'user' or filter == 'all':
        if filter == 'user':
            credit_set = profile.videocredit_set.filter(video__uploaded_by=profile)
        if filter == 'all':
            credit_set = profile.videocredit_set.all()

        if sort == 'alphabetical':
            credit_set = conform_videos_and_credits(credit_set, uncredited_videos, sort)
        if sort == 'newest':
            credit_set = conform_videos_and_credits(credit_set, uncredited_videos, sort)
        if sort =='position':
            credit_set = credit_set.order_by('position')
            list_of_credits = position_credit_set(profile, credit_set, filter, uncredited_videos)

    elif filter == 'others':
        credit_set = profile.videocredit_set.exclude(video__uploaded_by=profile)  
        if sort == 'alphabetical':
            credit_set = credit_set.order_by('video__title')
        if sort == 'newest':
            credit_set = credit_set.order_by('video__uploaded_at')
        if sort == 'position':
            credit_set = credit_set.order_by('position')
            list_of_credits = position_credit_set(profile, credit_set, filter, uncredited_videos)

    #### THIS IS THE PART THAT CAUSES THE ERROR ###
    else:
        ### if none of the above, call the function, passing default parameters ###
        profile_videos_sort_and_filter(profile, uncredited_videos=uncredited_videos,
                                        sort='position', filter='newest')

    return credit_set, list_of_credits
```

How would I change the final else clause to be valid? Thank you.

Comment: On a side note, you should avoid setting the default value of a function argument to a list (list_of_credits=[] in your example). See this for more info: http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a condition for `sort='position'` and/or `filter='newest'`.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you handle `filter=='newest'`? The code will loop forever unless you add an `elif filter=='newest'` and do something on that case.